# GeoFire Error No such module GeoFire

Tags: ios, swift, geofire

I would like to implement GeoFire for my CocoaPods Project. 
Therefore I added the following pod to my Podfile:

```
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
```

I tried to import GeoFire in my ViewController but XCode shows me the following error: `

> Error No such module GeoFire

In my Pods directory the GeoFire Pod is also shown like the screenshot shows:
[Pod Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssUbn.png)

I cannot find the issue

Comment: Did you save pod file and update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `GeoFire` target to `FirebaseDatabase` framework as in link below.

Please see this [link](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/51).